# The term is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path [...]

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, terminal

I'm trying to run a python file (any python file) using VsCode. Every time I press run and try to make a function call I get this message:

[image: error mesage]

The folder VsCode opens to read the file is the desktop folder where the file is saved. The VsCode python extension is installed. The python interpreter I'm using is Python 3.9.5 64-bit, which I downloaded from python.org. All of my python files run just fine on the python idle and Jupyter notebook. Any idea why this is happening and how I can fix it?

Comment: You are not using Python at all. The error message is coming from Powershell which of course does not understand Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to execute the function in `.py` file directly in terminal, you should enter [python interactive mode](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/interpreter.html#interactive-mode) first.

1. In integrated Terminal, type `python` to enter interactive mode
2. Import filename
3. Type `filename.function()` and press Enter to run it

[image]

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> to quit this mode.

Comment: @AleyHassan. Happy Coding:)